# Delete all task related to User

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am creating a todo app. I want to delete all task related to a particular user from Tasklist table after login but i got an error ' **deleteAll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'** ". How can i delete all task. Thanks in advance.

Model.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User

 from django.db import models

 class TaskList(models.Model):

       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

       task = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

       complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

       taskCreate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Views.py

```
 def deleteAll(request, id):

      TaskList.objects.filter(id=request.user.tasklist_set.filter(id)).delete()

      return redirect('todolist')
```

Html

```
 {% extends 'home.html' %}

 {% block content %}

  {%if user.is_authenticated%}

    <h2>Welcome   {{ user.get_username| title }}</h2>

    <button type="submit"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></button>

    <form method="post">

     {% csrf_token %}

      <label for="task">

        <input name="task" placeholder="add today's task" id="task" required>

          <button type="submit">add</button>

      </label>
    </form>

    <form method="get" >
      {% csrf_token %}

         <div>

            {% for todo in task  %}

               {% if todo.complete %}

                <li class="list-group-item todo-completed"><h6>{{ todo.task|linebreaks}}                          </h6></li>
                {% else %}

                    <a href="{% url 'complete' todo.id%}"> <h6 class="list">{{ todo.task|linebreaks}}</h6></a>
                {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

         <button><a href="{% url 'delete' %}"> Delete All </a></button>

        <button><a href="{% url 'deleteComplete' %}"> Delete Completed </a></button>

    </div>

    </form>

{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Change in your template Delete All button. Because your view requires a user id.

```
<button type="button"><a href="{% url 'delete' user.id %}"> Delete All </a></button>
```

Then simplify the deleteAll functions db query. You need to filter all tasks of current user. so you can just use `user__id__exact = id`:

```
def deleteAll(request, id):
      TaskList.objects.filter(user__id__exact = id).delete()
      return redirect('todolist')
```

**Alternative Solution:**
You don't need to send id. because you can get the current user id in request argument.
You just need to change the filter:

```
# view
@login_required
def deleteAll(request):
      TaskList.objects.filter(user = request.user).delete()
      return redirect('todolist')

# In template use:
<button type="button"><a href="{% url 'delete' %}"> Delete All </a></button>

# urlpattern
path('delete/', deleteAll, name='delete')
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: can u tell me one thing if u don't mind what's the issue in my query

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common mistake that people do. :)

You have defined a function which takes `request` and an argument named as `id` as shown here:

```
 def deleteAll(request, id):

      TaskList.objects.filter(id=request.user.tasklist_set.filter(id)).delete()

      return redirect('todolist')
```

But you have to pass an argument into `deleteAll`. To do that you have to type in the argument value.

You can do so by entering the value after `{% url 'delete' %}` in the line

`<a href="{% url 'delete' %}"> Delete All </a>`

For example:
`<a href="{% url 'delete' **todo.id** %}"> Delete All </a>`

I hope this helped, if not, feel free to comment and clarify the query.

Comment: Basically i want to delete all task related to particular user  when u click delete task

Comment: if i add todo.id in delete button it just only a single task at a time

Comment: in that case you must enter the argument as ```<a href="{% url 'delete' request.user.pk %}"> Delete All </a>``` and the view should be changed to ```TaskList.objects.filter(id=id).delete()``` more easier solution is to remove the argument itself and in the view do this ```TaskList.objects.filter(id=request.user.pk).delete()```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose "id" refers to the user's id, that is `request.user.pk`.

There are two issues, or two solutions:

#### About the Error

You have specified that your view expects the argument `id`, therefore you would need to add it to the URL in the template.

```
def deleteAll(request, id): # <<<< "id" is specified as argument

<a href="{% url 'delete' %}"> Delete All </a>  <!-- no "id" is specified -->
```

If you have an argument in a view, you need to specify it in the urls.py (which you obviously did) and subsequently whereever you need it reversed:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete' id=request.user.pk %}"> Delete All </a>
```

You need the request template processor to have the request in your template context.

However, you actually don't need the ID because you know it in the view already. This is the "other solution".

#### About the ID

```
def deleteAll(request, id):
    TaskList.objects.filter(id=request.user.tasklist_set.filter(id)).delete()
    return redirect('todolist')
```

can be rewritten to

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def deleteAll(request):
    TaskList.objects.filter(id=request.user.pk).delete()
    return redirect('todolist')
```

You need to remove the `id` argument in the url in your urls.py, as well.

Comment: i removed id from url now it show " failed: Reverse for 'delete' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteall$'] "

Comment: You need to remove the argument from your template. You probably added it after reading the other answers. You should revert your template to what you have posted in your question.